Index on column with "datetime2" data type
I'd like to cut down on the scope of a query towards a table that has a timestamp column on the format: 2024-12-01 12:34:56.1234567. (A "datetime2" data type)
Assuming 10 million rows and assuming my strategy for cutting the query scope to recent entries is "where Timestamp > MY_CUTOFF_DATE", my question is
Should those nanoseconds/seconds/minutes/hours be something to worry about when adding an index on the Timestamp column?
If the Timestamp format would have been "2024-12-01" (date) my guess is that I wouldn't have been worried about performance for my purpose and requirements. But adding the full time down to 100 nanoseconds makes this unknown territory for me.
I know I should test, but I don't have access to the large production table and was hoping to not have to put time into filling a test table with realistic time data, if someone would answer "Don't worry about it if you're not chasing performance gains below 2 seconds".

You mentioned timestamp but do you mean data type datetime or datetime2 (which store temporal values as binary structures, not as a formatted string)?

@DanGuzman I've edited for clarity, I believe we use the datetime2 format

Don't worry about it, you won't see a performance difference.

Thinking about it now, I guess my main concerns should be write performance and index size, and none of them are crucial in this particular case

I did some test with 2 tables, the first with datetime, the second with datetime2. I tested it with clustered index on the date col, and also with nonclustered index on the date col.
I see no difference in size on table/index and also no difference in performance.
I did the test only with 1 million records, not with 10 million, but I think that it will not change my conclusion.

Testing is always your bestest friend and far outweighs what someone says on the internet. Well done.
